# How can you call a function multiple times with format within a string to write to a file in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to create a xml file for Flam3 that contains multiple forms. I'm new to Common Lisp and I'm sure there's a much better way to do what I'm trying to do.
Instead of calling the sexy function multiple times how can I just do a quick and dirty loop?

Here is the code in question:

```
;What the xml file should look like 
;A nice little template
(defun sexy ()
 (format nil
"<flame time=\"~d\" palette=\"~d\" zoom=\"~d\" size=\"640 480\" center=\"~d ~d\"   background=\"0 0 0\" brightness=\"~d\" gamma=\"~d\" vibrancy=\"3\" hue=\"~d\">
<xform weight=\"~f\" color=\"~f\" spherical=\"~d\" coefs=\"~f ~f ~f ~f ~f ~f\"/>
<xform weight=\"~f\" color=\"~f\" julia=\"~d\" coefs=\"~f ~f ~f ~f ~f ~f\"/>
<xform weight=\"~f\" color=\"~f\" rings=\"~d\" coefs=\"~f ~f ~f ~f ~f ~f\"/>
<xform weight=\"~f\" color=\"~f\" butterfly=\"~d\" coefs=\"~f ~f ~f ~f ~f ~f\"/>
</flame>" 
(random 100) (random 100) (random 3) (random 4) (random 4) (random 255) (random 10)  (random 10) 
(random 1.0) (random 1.0) 1 (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random    1.0) (random 1.0) 
(random 1.0) (random 1.0) 1 (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) 
(random 1.0) (random 1.0) 1 (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) 
(random 1.0) (random 1.0) 1 (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) (random 1.0) 
))

;Actually write the file using the sexy function
;But call it 10 times to create 10 different structures with random values
(defun xml-maker ()
  (with-open-file (my-stream "test.flam3" :direction :output 
             :if-exists :supersede)
      (format my-stream
"<test> ~a ~a ~a ~a ~a ~a ~a ~a ~a ~a </test>" (sexy) (sexy) (sexy) (sexy) (sexy) (sexy)      (sexy) (sexy) (sexy) (sexy) )))

;Just call the program with the newly written file
(defun fract-maker ()
 (progn (xml-maker)
    (ext:shell "flam3-render < test.flam3")))
```

Comment: What is the question? How to repeat 10 times the call to function `sexy` ?

Comment: Yes.When I call loop do on the sexy function it doesn't add the strings to the file. I use the nil parameter in hopes that it will just return the string but that doesn't work.

Comment: Lol thanks .. Just wish it wasn't true ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
(format my-stream "<test>~{ ~A~} </test>"
    (loop
        :repeat 10 
        :collecting (sexy)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why also not do the output directly?

```
(format t "~a ~a" (format nil "$~a$" 10) (format nil "$~a$" 20))
```

Above generates two strings and then the outer format prints them.

Why not instead do the printing directly?

```
(format t "$~a$" 10)
(format t " ")
(format t "$~a$" 20)
```

or even

```
(format t "$~a$ $~a$" 10 20)
```

or something like

```
(format t "~{ $~a$~}" '(10 20))
```

Comment: I dont think I quite understand. Would I still be able to write the string to a file?

Comment: @masterofnothing: output in Common Lisp goes to streams. Just pass the stream to write to around. Creating strings in output functions is wasteful and in most cases not necessary.